# What is the best way to filter for a specific and rolling date range in a PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql

If I want to run a report on the 20th of every month and need to filter from the 13th of last month to the 13th of current month.

How can I do it? For example, if I run this query on 2023-04-20, I expect the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE dt > '2023-03-13' AND dt < '2023-04-13';
```

Comment: Where is the expected result and what's wrong with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL select count with dynamic date range](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201905/postgresql-select-count-with-dynamic-date-range)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like one of your conditions should include "or equal to" component, or else the exact value of the 13th will not be included in any month's report, which is improbable to be the desired outcome.

One way to approach this would be with date_trunc and interval math:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE 
    dt > date(date_trunc('month',now())+interval '12 days'-interval '1 month') and 
    dt <= date(date_trunc('month',now())+interval '12 days');
```